# How to define eventhandler on React class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting out with ReactJS and I am trying to trigger the `onCLick` event on a button:

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var ExampleApplication = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        var message ='Joko';

        return <div><p>{message}</p><button onClick=function() {console.log("hi")}>hier</button></div>;
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <ExampleApplication />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

How can I display the `console.log` message and triggering the `onClick` event? The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 9: XJS value should be either an expression or a quoted XJS text
    at http://localhost:63343/react-0.11.2/examples/basic-jsx-external/example.js:9:53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap that onClick as such:

```
return <div><p>{message}</p><button onClick={function() {console.log("hi")}}>hier</button></div>;
```

As it stands, `onClick=function(){}` does not make that function into a JSX expression.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gwm6dd4n/

Answer (score 0):

React's JSX syntax is only syntactical sugar which gets converted into regular JS. Anytime you wish to inject regular JS into it, you need to use squigglies around that. The event handler definition in the code lacks the surrounding {}. And may I recommend the more succinct lambda expression instead... Use

```
onclick={()=> console.log("hi")}
```